# Creating an axis2 module that intercept soap data

Tags: java, apache-axis

I have already created a module that is an extension of axis2 and I want this module doing a simple operation like addition for example.
What sould I do to intercept the treatment of the web service (obtain the ws data) and do the operation of addition inside the handler.

Answer (score 2):

Please go through the following article, this provided a step by step guide for creating an axis2 module to intercept SOAP data.
http://www.packtpub.com/article/apache-axis2-web-services-writing-module

you need to write your class that extends AbstractHandler and implements Handler.
then you need to override the invoke method where you would be able to get the SOAP context.
You can do whatever you want with this SOAP context.

Oh, and you also have to define your module in the module.xml configuration.

Comment: Link no longer works, but this will explain what is needed: https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/modules.html